# Trouble with functions and local storage

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, local-storage

This code originally took input.value and added it to the page. I added local storage to this project and the code is already written but I’m having a hard time displaying the input to the page from localStorage. The input is stored in local storage as objects in an array. I wrote a for loop to loop through those values and pass them to functions that builds the element and appends it to the li and later appends to the ul. It’s not displaying on the page and I’m not getting any errors in the console. I'm not sure where to turn so heres my code:

```
function fetchInvite() {
     const rsvpInvite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Invitees"));
     const rsvpList = document.getElementById('invitedList'); 

    for(var i = 0; i < rsvpInvite.length; i++) {
        const name = rsvpInvite[i].name;
        const confirm = rsvpInvite[i].confirmed;
        createLI(name, confirm);

    function createLI(name, confirm) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');

    function createElement(elementName, property, value) {
        const element = document.createElement(elementName);

        element[property] = value;
        return element;
    }
    function appendToLI (elementName, property, value) {
        const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
        li.appendChild(element);
        return element;
    }

appendToLI('span', 'textContent', name);
appendToLI('label', 'textContent', confirm)
.appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
appendToLI('button', 'textContent', 'edit');
appendToLI('button', 'textContent', 'remove');
return li;
```

}

}
}

The full project is available here: https://github.com/tianniNakiMyers/RSVP_TeamTreeHouse/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Can you please check out the code you posted! It doesn't match the code in the link and there seems to be some mistakes (probably typos). Are the functions really defined inside the loop?

Comment: Oh it’s the same code, I just inserted the function inside to for loop bc I was playing around with it trying to figure it out. Typos in the code? or... Idk is there a better way to pass the values from the for loop to the functions. I thought about rewriting them as function expressions but that might be overthinking it and creating more work then needed. I’m still very new to functional programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you probably never called `fetchInvite`.

Apart from that, here is a refactoring of your code:

```
function elt(parent, tag, text) {                                        // create element of tagname tag and append it to a parent (if provided) then set its textContent to text and return it
    var el = document.createElement(tag);
    if(parent) {
        parent.appendChild(el);
    }
    el.textContent = text;
    return el;
}

function fetchInvite() {
    const rsvpInvite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Invitees"));
    const rsvpList = document.getElementById('invitedList');

    for(var i = 0; i < rsvpInvite.length; i++) {
        const name = rsvpInvite[i].name;
        const confirm = rsvpInvite[i].confirmed;

        const li = elt(rsvpList, 'li', '');                              // create an li element with empty text and append it to rsvpList
        elt(li, 'span', name);                                           // create a span whose text is name and append it to li
        elt(elt(li, 'label', confirm), 'input', '').type = 'checkbox';   // create an input append it to a label element that contain the text confirm and that is appended to li, then set type of input to 'checkbox'
        elt(li, 'button', 'edit');                                       // ...
        elt(li, 'button', 'remove');
    }
}

fetchInvite(); // don't forget to call it
```